"Touch target size too small" for ImageButton with large minWidth and minHeight
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonFoo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white_24dp"/>

I don't know why Android Studio gives warning:

imageButtonFoo : Touch target size too small. This item's
width is 25dp. Consider making the width of this touch target 48dp or
larger.

minWidth and minHeight do not seem to have any effect on this warning.
Could anyone shed some light on this?
